# pgfplot | tikzpicture | changing length + width of ticks

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, ticks

While there are any number of posts on how to fiddle (from the Latin) with tick labels, or tick placements, or tick color, I haven't been able to find anything (in terms of worked examples, or in the documentation), for how to change the length and width of the ticks themselves. Perhaps I simply haven't found the right search phrase(s).

At any rate, the question probably doesn't need an MWE, but to provide one for a simple 'answer by demonstration', here is a simple plot where I'd like to decrease the length (distance from top of tick mark to axis) by (say) 50%, relative to the default length. Thanks much in advance.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
      [width=190pt,axis x line=middle, axis y line=center, 
      tick align=outside,
      xmin=0.3,xmax=7.7,ymin=0.44,ymax=1.05,
      xlabel={\emph{x-axis label}},ylabel={\emph{y-axis label}},
      xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7},ytick={0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0},
      x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.1)},anchor=north},
      y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.1,.5)},rotate=90,anchor=south},
      every tick/.style={black,semithick,height=1cm},
      ylabel style={yshift=0.2cm}, xlabel style={yshift=-0.2cm}]
        \addplot+[mark=none,smooth, thick]  plot coordinates {
            (1,1)
            (2,0.75)
            (3,0.666)
            (4,0.625)
            (5,0.6)
            (6,0.5833)
            (7,0.571)
        };
        \addplot [red, dashed, no markers, thick] coordinates {(0.3,0.5) (7.7,0.5)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 25):

The tick length can be configured with option `major tick length` (or the alias `tickwidth`. Minor ticks are configured with option `minor tick length` (or `subtickwidth`). In this case, we have major ticks only. The default is `0.15cm` and can be derived by `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/major tick length}`. I found the option names in section "4.15.4 Tick Fine-Tuning" of the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf) of `pgfplots`.

Example, which sets the tick length to 50 % of the default:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\MajorTickLength{
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/major tick length} * 0.5
    }
    \begin{axis}[ 
      width=190pt,
      axis x line=middle,
      axis y line=center,
      tick align=outside,
      xmin=0.3, 
      xmax=7.7, 
      ymin=0.44,
      ymax=1.05,
      xlabel={\emph{x-axis label}},
      ylabel={\emph{y-axis label}},
      xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7},
      ytick={0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0},
      x label style={
        at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.1)},
        anchor=north,
      },
      y label style={
        at={(axis description cs:-0.1,.5)},
        rotate=90,   
        anchor=south,
      },
      major tick length=\MajorTickLength,
      every tick/.style={
        black,
        semithick,
      },
      ylabel style={yshift=0.2cm},
      xlabel style={yshift=-0.2cm}
    ]
        \addplot+[mark=none,smooth, thick]  plot coordinates {
            (1,1)     
            (2,0.75)  
            (3,0.666) 
            (4,0.625) 
            (5,0.6)   
            (6,0.5833)
            (7,0.571)
        };
        \addplot [red, dashed, no markers, thick] coordinates {(0.3,0.5)
        (7.7,0.5)};
    \end{axis}   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

## Bold tick numbers

<sup>This is an answer to CroCo's [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247627/pgfplot-tikzpicture-changing-length-width-of-ticks/247629?noredirect=1#comment673078_247629) and to Dr. Manuel Kuehner's [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247627/pgfplot-tikzpicture-changing-length-width-of-ticks/247629?noredirect=1#comment1452654_247629).</sup>

Bold tick numbers can be set via option `tick label style`. Since the tick numbers are set in math mode by default (see `\axisdefaultticklabel`), `\boldmath` gets bold tick numbers.

Key `tick label style` appends to `every tick/.style`, thus the following updated example (using `pgfplots` 1.17) merges the two keys:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\MajorTickLength{
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/major tick length} * 0.5
    }
    \begin{axis}[
      width=190pt,
      axis x line=middle,
      axis y line=center,
      tick align=outside,
      xmin=0.3,
      xmax=7.7,
      ymin=0.44,
      ymax=1.05,
      xlabel={\emph{x-axis label}},
      ylabel={\emph{y-axis label}},
      xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7},
      ytick={0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0},
      x label style={
        at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.1)},
        anchor=north,
      },
      y label style={
        at={(axis description cs:-0.1,.5)},
        rotate=90,
        anchor=south,
      },
      major tick length=\MajorTickLength,
      ylabel style={yshift=0.2cm},
      xlabel style={yshift=-0.2cm},
      tick label style={black, semithick, font=\boldmath},
    ]
        \addplot+[mark=none,smooth, thick]  plot coordinates {
            (1,1)
            (2,0.75)
            (3,0.666)
            (4,0.625)
            (5,0.6)
            (6,0.5833)
            (7,0.571)
        };
        \addplot [red, dashed, no markers, thick] coordinates {(0.3,0.5)
        (7.7,0.5)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with bold tick numbers]

Comment: Danke -- not sure how I missed that option (or perhaps I saw it, and didn't connect the dots that it applied to my 'problem').

Comment: How to make only the tick numbers bold?

Comment: @CroCo See updated answer.

Comment: I tried `\boldmath,` but eventually, I needed to use `font=\boldmath`.